# Users can't save their address

Tags: customer-address

I'm totally new with Magento, I have 10 years of experience with Drupal, but it's the first time I'm working with Magento so please pardon any approximation and lack of culture about it.

I'm just given this project which is in the middle. And I have some bugs to correct.

Initially it was in Magento 1.9.2.2.
Users couldn't save their address, which is indeed critical. I have upgraded to 1.9.3.1 and the problem persists, as I am absolutely not aware about the internals at the moment, I have no idea about what can cause this.

Simply the address is never saved, and when I try to save, it is falling back on the empty form.

Any clue so that I can provide more information to solve that ?

Here is the log when i try to save address.

```
    ==> axis_exception.log <== 
2016-11-16T11:15:28+00:00 ERR (3):  
Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Header in /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/Mage.php:595 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...') 
#1 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_Page_Block...', Array) 
#2 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/header', 'header') 
#3 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/header', 'header') 
#4 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#5 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#6 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() 
#7 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks() 
#8 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') 
#9 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') 
#10 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction() 
#11 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') 
#12 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#13 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#14 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#15 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') 
#16 /var/www/magento_debugger/index.php(203): require('/var/www/mybaby...') 
#17 {main}
```

Also strangely the current url always appears in the search bar as shown on the screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom theme ? If so could you try to switch to the default/default theme and see if the error persists.

Comment: The theme is rwd ... it comes with magento from my understanding :-(

Comment: is it rwd/default ? or a custom version of rwd ?

Comment: default, coming right from the code.
One thing strange, is that the string  /customer/address/new/ appears in the search bar when I'm trying to create an address  .... Could the two problems be linked ?

Comment: not too sure. Do you have any error in your Magento logs or server error logs ?

Comment: I've just updated the code with logs when i try to save.

Comment: @jmary I doubt this log error is directly related to the problem that you are facing. It looks like an exception which created while you tried to load your home page

Answer (score 0):

Such block does not exist by default in Magento: `Mage_Page_Block_Header`

There's probably an issue with your layout or a module layout.

You can try finding the wrong layout by using the following command on your Magento folder:

```
grep -ri "page/header" .
```

Once you found it you can replace it with `page/html_header` which is the right block type

Comment: I tried that, and it was concerning /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Header.php, but changing $this->setTemplate('page/header.phtml'); to $this->setTemplate('page/html_ header.phtml'); makes the user to be logged out at trying to save address.

Comment: @jmary no roll that back that's not it. look for something like `type="page/header"` or `createBlock('page/header')`

Comment: The grep command was replying :
 ju-Latitude-E5540 /var/www/mybabyhk/mybabyhk # grep -ri "page/header" . 
./app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Header.php:        $this->setTemplate('page/header.phtml');

Other lines are reffering to var/log

I have now reverted to the situation before the upgrade to 1.9.3.1. So I am in 1.9.2.2 : it doesn't show any erro. The logs are silent, but saving address fails and it says nothing ...

Comment: It's a nightmare ...

Comment: @jmary do you get an error in the browser console ? like a 500 error ?

Comment: Not at all ... it comes back happily to the form.

Comment: @jmary can you try disabling all the non core modules and try again ?

Comment: I did :-| try to do this ... I will pm you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48596/discussion-between-jmary-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).